# How to handle the same code path with different parameters?

Tags: c#, oop, code-duplication

I've encountered a situation where, trying not to have to modify the underlying source (it's not really "my" code at that level; otherwise, I'd love to modify it), I have two almost identical code paths, but with separate types of data I'm using.

Ignoring that you could probably convert one to the other rather easily, a similar **example** would be a "Circle" object.

On one hand, I have a `Point` object and a radius.  On the other, I have a `Circle` object.  Both of these can describe the same actual circle, but I just can't convert one to another.

Then, in my code, I have:

```
void Run(Circle circle)
{
    if(AllNegative(circle))
    {
        // ...
        // Do unrelated stuff
        // ...
        ColorCircle(circle);
        // ...
    }
}

void Run(Point pt, uint radius)
{
    if(AllNegative(pt, radius))
    {
        // ...
        // Do unrelated stuff
        // ...
        ColorCircle(pt, radius);
        // ...
    }
}

bool AllNegative(Circle circle) { return (circle.AllNegative); }
bool AllNegative(Point pt, uint radius) { return ((pt.X + radius) < 0) && ((pt.Y + radius) < 0); }

void ColorCircle(Circle circle) { /* ... */ }
void ColorCircle(Point pt, uint radius) { /* ... */ }
```

Of course, I have more code in `Run` than in this example.

How do I merge `Run` into a single function in order to minimize code duplication?

Comment: *Why* can't you convert between Point/radius and Circle? What's stopping you?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The `Circle` class is a factory class; I can't just instantiate my own `Circle` object.

Comment: And there's no factory method which creates a relevant Circle? And you can't get a Point and a radius from the Circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two paths you could take in this case:

1. You can leave it just as you have it now - overloaded methods.
2. Move duplicated code to a new method. If in your `unrelated` section you calculate the diameter of the circle (realistic or not), create a method `calcDiameter(radius)`.

There's nothing inherantly wrong with duplicated code in this sort of situation, if it's only a couple of lines that really don't make a new method practical.

Answer (score 1):

An example with generics:

```
public interface ICircle
{
    Point Point{get;}
    uint Radius{get;}
    ... add whatever you need
}

public class MyCircle: ICircle
{
   private Circle _circle;
   ... implement interface
}

public class MyCircle2: ICircle
{
   private Point _point;
   private uint _radius;
   ... implement interface
}

void Run<T>(T circle) where T: ICircle
{
    if(AllNegative(circle))
    {
        ColorCircle(circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ColorCircle(circle);` imply that `Point` and `Radius` can be converted to Circle?

Comment: No as the Run method only nows the ICircle interface. The inconvenient is you need to define two "wrapper" classes, MyCircle, and MyCircle2 - the names are stupid allright :)

Comment: But the `ICircle` interface doesn't hold the information that `ColorCircle` requires to do its work. Or, at least you are duplicating the point/radius information for the `MyCircle` class (as it is presumably contained within `Circle`

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, you could do your `unrelated stuff` in a separate method and call it from each `Run`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a common interface for the both of them that would look something like this:

```
public interface IMyShape
{
    public bool IsNegative();
    public void Color();
}
```

Then you would only need one method that accepted an IMyShape reference:

```
void Run(IMyShape shape)
{
    if(shape.AllNegative())
    {
        // ...
        // Do unrelated stuff
        // ...
        shape.Color();
        // ...
    }
}
```